# If $b\mid ca$, then $b\mid a$. Is this true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, discrete-mathematics

My proof: We want to show $b\mid a$ i.e. $a = bn$ for some integer $n$. Since $b\mid ca$, $ca = bm$ for some integer $m$. Substituting for $a$ gives us $c(bn) = bm \Rightarrow b(cn) = bm\dots$

After that I get stuck. I get the feeling that this may be false.

Comment: Let b=ca>a. ***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$4\mid 2\cdot 6\implies 4\mid 6...?$$

Comment: Thanks. Everyone provided the answers I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

**False**. Take $b=2$, $a=3$, and $c=0$. Or $c=2$. Or $c$ any even number.

What is **true** is: if $(b,c)=1$ (i.e. $b$ and $c$ are relatively prime) and if $b\mid ac$ then $b\mid a$.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, in that this is false.  In your proof, you are assuming what you want to prove:

You wrote "Substituting for $a$ gives us $c(bn)=bm$," where you used the equation $a=bn$ for your substitution. But $a=bn$ is *exactly* what you want to prove!

Comment: I don't see how he's assuming what he wants to prove.

Comment: @LokiClock He wrote "Substituting for $a$ gives us $c(bn)=bm$," where he used the equation $a=bn$ for his substitution.  But $a=bn$ is _exactly_ what he wants to prove!  At the beginning of his post, he wrote, "We want to show $b∣a$ i.e. $a=bn$ for some integer $n$."

Comment: Ah. I misread that. Could you put that in your answer?

Comment: @LokiClock No problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the proposition ***is false***:

***To prove a claim is false***, use proof by **counterexample** (for which you need to provide only one counterexample, and you are done!)

Consider the obvious counter examples where $b \mid c$ but $b \not\mid a$: in these cases we would still have $b\mid ca$, *but only because* $b \mid c$.

Consider, e.g. $b = 2, c = 4, a = 5$: $b\mid ca$ but $b\not\mid a$.

Simpler yet, the counterexample $b = 2, c = 2, a = 3$ suffices.

Comment: Nice examples like this are so helpful! +1